# How to change the limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I am attempting to solve the integral of the following...

$$\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdr\Theta $$

So I do the following step...

$$=2 \pi\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdr$$

but then the next step is to substitute $s = -r^2$ which results in...

$$=2 \pi\int_{- \infty}^{0}\frac{1}{2}e^{s}ds$$

The limits of integration are reversed now and the $r$ somehow results in $1/2$.

Can someone explain why this works? Why did substituting cause the limits change and result in the integration above?

Comment: $$s = -r^{2} \implies ds = -2r dr \implies -ds/2 = rdr$$ and as $r \to \infty$, $s \to - \infty$ and as $r \to 0$, $s \to 0$.

Comment: This constellation of consequences is why I recommend to my students to set $s = r^2$.  This gives fewer minus signs and since the substituent is monotonically increasing, does not reverse the order of the bounds of integration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$s=-r^{2}$ gives $ds=-2rdr$ so $dr =-\frac 1 {2r} ds$. Also, as $r$ increases from $0$ to $\infty$, $s$ decreases from $0$ to $-\infty$.

Comment: It should be noted that the minus sign from the substitution is then used to reverse the order of the limits.

Comment: @JohnDoe Right. I didn't mention it explicitly but  that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need substitution. We already know the antiderivative of $re^{-r^2}$ and it is $-e^{-r^2}\over 2$

Comment: This perhaps repeats something the OP already knows.  In any case it offers no help with the issue of changing limits of integration raised by the Question.